# Java NetBeans: GUI stuck when calling PrintWriter.write();

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, netbeans

I am starting a GUI-based project that serves for shopping and downloading e-books.
So far I have four classes: Client, Server, ServerThread and Login (GUI form).
Program is stuck when I type in username and password and hit "Login" button.
I run Server on command line, and Login from NetBeans and they seem to be connected.
Socket.isConnected() returns true.
Also, there was one time when I think I accidentally run two Login's and it worked and didn't stuck on one of them.
Any ideas why this happens?

Client.java

```
package Client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    private static final int PORT = 9000;
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintWriter output;

    public Client () {
        try {
            InetAddress serverIP = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            sock = new Socket (serverIP,PORT);
            input = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter ( sock.getOutputStream())),true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean login(String user, String password) {
        output.write("LOGIN " + user + "#" + password); //information about user and password are in a form "user#password" in users.txt
        output.flush();
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = input.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        if (response != null) {
            return response.equals("SUCCESS");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
package Server;

import java.io.*; import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    private static final int PORT = 9000;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while (true) {
                Socket sock = serversocket.accept();
                //new ServerThread(sock).start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } 
}
```

ServerThread.java

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private Socket sock;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter output;


    public ServerThread (Socket sock) {
        System.out.println("ServerThread konstruktor");
        this.sock = null;
        try {
            this.sock = sock;
            input = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
            output =  new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter ( sock.getOutputStream())),true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ServerThread.run()");
        while (true) {
            try {
                String request = null;
                request = input.readLine(); 
                if ( request.startsWith("LOGIN")) {
                    String userpass = request.split(" ")[1];
                    BufferedReader citac;
                    citac = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\HP USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bookholic\\src\\resources\\users.txt"));
                    String line = null;
                     while ( (line = citac.readLine()) != null) {
                         if (line.equals(userpass)) {
                             output.write("SUCCESS");
                             output.flush();
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
package gui;

import Client.Client;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Client client;

    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        client = new Client();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        tbUsername = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tbPassword = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnLogin.setText("Login");
        btnLogin.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btnPrijavaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(btnLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(tbUsername)
                    .addComponent(tbPassword))
                .addGap(165, 165, 165))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(tbUsername, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(tbPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnLogin)
                .addGap(78, 78, 78))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnLoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
         if (client.login(tbUsername.getText(),tbPassword.getText())) {
             System.out.println("SUCCESS");
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("FAIL");
         }
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLogin;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tbUsername;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tbPassword;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

There are compilation errors possible, since I corrected name of some variables *here* while doing copy-paste.
Also, ServerThread.run() is implemented as while-loop because user will do many things, except login, which I will add later.

Comment: I do not see an `ouput.write("\r\n");` or `println`.

Comment: I use `output.write()` with `output.flush()` and it usually works.

Comment: If the server does not expect a whole line ending in a CR-LF.

Comment: I tired with `\r\n` and it doesn't work...

Comment: I tried with different approach. I used `SwingWorker` class to maintain connection with server in background and it worked without any problem.

Comment: Just to recommend to all of you who will be working with NetBeans GUI in Java - use SwingWorker. :)